# Draw a line that goes from fix point t moving div, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to draw a line that goes from a fix point of the webpage to a div that can be moved by mouse. I would like when the user move the div that the line "follow", that it adapts to like the fix point and the moving div. What tool are you thinking I should use?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think you can do that with svg, dynamically change the x,y coords of the end of the svg line with the coords of the x,y of the div when that div is moved

Comment: The problem with that is that I also need to change svg frame coordinates...

Comment: what if u make the svg big as the window positioned absolute and then on top of it u have the divs?

Comment: Problem is my window is an app, and if I put the svg on it I can't access buttons anymore...